# Is button tag in p tag allowed?

Tags: html, button, tags

Hey am confused that can we use  `<button></button>` in `<p></p>`. I know it works but is it a good practice.
Ex:

```
<p>I love cars <button>Love</buttons></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly use a button in a paragraph.  It's [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2).

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. In `<p>` tags, you can use `phrasing content`. As you can see here, the `<button>` is part of it.

```
Elements belonging to this category are <abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <data>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <picture>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <u>, <var>, <video>, <wbr> and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).
```

See for reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p